# ssh key not working on linux hosting

Tags: linux, git, macos, ssh, bitbucket

I'm trying to use an ssh key with git on my linux hosting service.

I did check a ton of guides but none seems to work for me, so maybe some human help will.

This is what i've done:

- I have already a keypair on my mac with a public and private key
- I have added this public key to bitbucket
- If (from the mac) i type in ssh -T git@bitbucket.org it asks for the psw and the it says i'm logged in, which means it is working and the keys are correct

Now, on the linux server host:

- I go to ~/.ssh/ and in here i have this files:

> authorized_keys -> /etc/support.pub (i cannot access this because
>   of host limitations)
>
> authorized_keys2 -> with my public id_rsa (format: id_rsa #######)
>
> id_rsa -> my public key (format: id_rsa #######)

I also created a file called config which looks like this:

Host bitbucket.com-{username}
     HostName bitbucket.com
     User git
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

but when i type: `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org`

i get this error: `Permission denied (publickey).`

the verbose log shows this:

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 3: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [104.......] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version conker_1.0.315-a08d059 app-132
debug1: no match: conker_1.0.315-a08d059 app-132
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-SiteGround_Inc
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 97:8c:1b:.......
debug1: Host 'bitbucket.org' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
```

what am i missing? None of the example, forum or google searches helped me with this, neither the hosting support.

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT**

ls -la ~/.ssh outputs this:

```
drwx------  2 user user 4096 Dec 12 17:22 .
drwx--x--x 16 user user 4096 Dec 12 16:52 ..
lrwxrwxrwx  1 user user   16 Sep 16  2014 authorized_keys -> /etc/support.pub
-rw-------  1 user user    0 Dec 12 17:23 authorized_keys2
-rw-r--r--  1 user user  381 Dec 12 17:21 id_rsa
```

Comment: Have you set up a ssh config for the client to use the relevant `identityfile` or added the idendity with `ssh-agent`?

Comment: "it asks for the psw" - if it's asking for password then something isn't right, I think - it means it's not using your key.

Comment: The first time it is. The local machine is correct. the issue is on the hosting server @OliverCharlesworth

Comment: @vmonteco with ssh-agent i get -bash: ssh-agent: command not found

Comment: What's your distro?

Comment: @vmonteco Linux 3.12.18-clouder0 #85 SMP Mon Apr 3 10:28:14 EEST 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try these solutions :

## 1- `ssh-agent :`

Either use `ssh-agent` (that should probably be included with `openssh`) to manage the identities :

```
> eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
> ssh-add /path/to/private_key
```

## 2- `~/.ssh/config` file :

Either set up a ssh configuration at `~/.ssh/config` on your client. Here is an example for a github configuration :

```
Host github github.com
Hostname github.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github
```

## 3- [EDIT] : Passing the path to the identity file directly by CLI :

```
ssh -T git@bitbucket.org -i /path/to/key
```

Of course, the public key must be added to the `authorized_keys` file on the server side.

Comment: I cannot edit the authorized_keys, but i have something called authorized_keys2 with the key in it. I think it is a limitation of my hosting service?

Comment: @Nick The `autorized_keys` file should be managed directly with the bitbucket management tool so actually I think you don't have to worry about it. (But you would if you wanted to set up and manage your own ssh service). I think you just have to tell `ssh` to use your key.

Comment: i cannot use ssh-agent as i get an error. The config file now looks exactly like yours but i still get the same error as before (denied (public key)

Comment: @Nick You probably just have to install/set up `ssh-agent`. Can you add your config file content?
Also could you try the third solution I just added?

Comment: i cannot do anything that requires root i'm afraid. Your third solution gives me back this error: WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE
Permissions 0644 for 'github' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
bad permissions: ignore key: github
Permission denied (publickey).

Comment: @Nick Just set your permissions for your private key to 0700 (with `chmod`)

Comment: changing permission asked me for the psw but even if i typed it in correctly it still says the psw is wrong and i cannot access is

Comment: @Nick Where is the directory you're working on (`pwd`), what are the permissions and ownership on it (`ls -la`) and who are you logged in as (`whoami`, `id`)?

Comment: i am working on .ssh directory, as my user (not root as i cannot be root on a shared host) and the permission on the .ssh folder are drwx------ for my user

Comment: And can you add the `ls -la ~/.ssh` output to your question?

Comment: @Nick On your client *. All the solutions I mentionned are meant to be tried from the client machine. Not the server.

Comment: Oh ok sorry. I ll retry tonight when i get home from work

Answer (score 1):

The `authorized_keys2` file isn't read if `authorized_keys` exists and is valid, so nothing you put in there will have any effect. (It may not be read anyway on some configurations, since it's been deprecated for more than 15 years!). If you can't change your `authorized_keys` (e.g. using a web management interface), then you have no way to drop a key.